# Problem while trying to burn Ubuntu Live disc

Tags: cd

How can I find out the capabilities of my CDROM device? I've been trying to burn the live CD, but I can't. Ubuntu software says me there is no media in the CD drive. I then used a USB stick, but I'd like to use the CD drive too. Should I try to get a new hardware driver for it, since it does seem to be unable to recognise an empty disc.

Quite new to Ubuntu, or Linux in general, so please keep the solution simple.

Comment: Can it read other CDs in that drive?

Answer (score 1):

if this is a CD ROM drive like you said, it won't write disks. You can find with `sudo lshw` and searching for something like below in the answer to find out what is your CD drive:

```
       *-cdrom
            description: DVD-RAM writer
            product: DVDRAM GT30F
            vendor: HL-DT-ST
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /dev/cdrw
            logical name: /dev/dvd
            logical name: /dev/dvdrw
            logical name: /dev/scd0
            logical name: /dev/sr0
            version: TS08
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
            configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

But maybe your CD drive is damaged (or the empty disk). You could try with another disk and see if your drive can read other disks.